# React // Display keys of mapped array in state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I receive data from an open api which is stored in an array in state. Then I mapped the array to output it in list items and gave them keys additionally. (this is working so far)

1. I want to display the position of every element in the array in another list items. (this is not working). (The result should be 1-17 of course).
2. Then I want to compare every elements position to a given position. So, if ItemPosition[5] = 6 do...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {

  state = {
    teams: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.openligadb.de/api/getbltable/bl1/2019`)
      .then(res => {
        const teams = res.data;
        this.setState({ teams });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <ul>
      {this.state.teams.map(p => <li key={p.id}>{p.TeamName}</li>)}
      // next line is not correct
      {this.state.teams.map(t => <li key={t.id}>{t.key}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the index of the array as the second parameter of map like this:

```
{this.state.teams.map((t, index) => <li key={t.id}>{index}</li>)}
```

And you can use this index, to compare the items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, did it now!

Comment: Sry, here it is :) : 
  onClickButton = () => {
    if (this.state.teams[7].TeamName === "FC Bayern") {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        gram: prevState.gram + 1
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        gram: prevState.gram - (1 - this.state.teams.TeamName.findIndex(teamName => teamName.value === "FC Bayern"))
      }));
    }
  };

Comment: I want to test if a Teamname is at a special position in an array (working). If not I want to get the difference between a given number (in this case 1) and the position of the Teamname which i compared and update it to the state. A negativ result is okay and appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some data, how you save it and what your structure looks like ?

Comment: I did a fiddle for you of my component. Is this enough for you and can you see it?
https://jsfiddle.net/Van_Gram/n5q8dx2s/

Comment: Yes that would be enough

Comment: You have to change your findIndex function. It acts just like filter/map:  this.state.teams.findIndex(team => team.TeamName === "FC Bayern"). You iterate through the array and look for each item if that matches.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks :)